# Flicker in my phoneGap 3.5 app while scrolling list and select any of one to go at next page

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cordova-3.5

I'm developing a PhoneGap app with Cordova 3.5. I'm using `<ul><li>` to create a list view. When I select any item from listview without scrolling the list, it works, but when I select any item after scrolling the list then it first goes to the top of the list then goes to the next page. What's going on?

Comment: I wonder if anyone will be able to help you like this. Without your code & more info it's hard to say what's going on.

Comment: It's like a listview bro nothing else. @AtanuCSE